# Matching custom exceptions

Tags: java, assertj

The [Javadoc](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractAssert.html#matches-java.util.function.Predicate-) gives this example for the `matches` method:

```
assertThat(player).matches(p -> p.isRookie());
```

And indeed, when I define a dummy class Player, the above statement compiles ok. However, when I define a class that derives from Exception, then the following doesn't compile:

```
public class MyCustomException extends Exception {
    public boolean isMyCustomFieldSet() { return true; }
}
...
MyCustomException myCustomException = new MyCustomExcpetion();
assertThat(myCustomException).matches(e -> e.isMyCustomFieldSet());
```

I can make it compile by using a cast:

```
assertThat(myCustomException).matches(e -> ((MyCustomException)e).isMyCustomFieldSet());
```

but that cast looks "ugly" and a bit of a hack to work around some sort of deficiency. Can I make it compile in a "nicer" way, i.e. without using a cast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is in `Assertions`, it declares `AbstractThrowableAssert<?, ? extends Throwable> assertThat(Throwable t)` instead of `<T> AbstractThrowableAssert<?, T extends Throwable> assertThat(T t)`

But unfortunately this can not be done because of the following existing method that clashes with it: `public static <T> ObjectAssert<T> assertThat(T actual)`.

Casting is a solution, I agree it is not super elegant.

What I would do in that case is simply:

```
assertThat(myCustomException.isMyCustomFieldSet()).isTrue();
```

or to keep assertions on `myCustomException` directly:

```
assertThat(myCustomException).hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("myCustomFieldSet", true)
                             .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("myOtherField", "foo");
```

The drawback here is accessing fields by name which is not refactoring friendly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll be able to find a shorter way.

The issue is that

```
assertThat(new Player())
```

returns an `ObjectAssert<Player>`, with its `matches` signature being `matches(Predicate<? super Player>)`.

However,

```
assertThat(new MyException())
```

actually calls a different method `assertThat` which returns an `AbstractThrowableAssert<?, ? extends Throwable>` with a `matches(Predicate<? super Throwable>)`.

So that explains the issue, but I can't give you a better way to approach it.

I haven't checked whether an open issue exists against it, but it might be worth submitting one if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

As my acknowledge, there is no way to using the method **isMyCustomFieldSet** directly. Because the assert lib using generic class and a generic class cannot extend the Throwable class directly or indirectly.
[More info here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html)